# Sorting Into Columns(AS) with IF/CASE statements

Tags: mysql, case, one-to-many

I have a DB that is constructed as a one-to-many, where the many is as many as 3 "keywords". For example: Item A may have any/all of keywords B,C, and D. Each of these keywords has a description that corresponds to it. How would I go about selecting the description of the keyword(s) that the item has?

My table looks like:

```
Item----Keyword----Description    
A-------B--------------desc1    
A-------C--------------desc2
```

If Item A has keywords C and D, and the description for C is "desc1" and the description for D is "desc2", I'd like my output to be:

```
Item---KeyB---KeyC---KeyD

A------NULL---desc1---desc2
```

Sorry for the poor formatting, I'm not sure how to do tables here. I've tried

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN Keyword = 'B' THEN Description AS 'KeyB'
WHEN Keyword = 'C' THEN Description AS 'KeyC'
WHEN Keyword = 'D' THEN Description AS 'KeyD'
END
```

However this gives me an error because 'AS' is used incorrectly.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: You can google for `PIVOT` or `DYNAMIC PIVOT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use conditional aggregation

```
 SELECT item, 
        MAX( CASE WHEN  Keyword = 'B' THEN Description END) as KeyB,
        MAX( CASE WHEN  Keyword = 'C' THEN Description END) as KeyC,
        MAX( CASE WHEN  Keyword = 'D' THEN Description END) as KeyD
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY  item
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the column name dynamically like you did.But you can try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Keyword = 'B' THEN 'KeyB' 
            WHEN Keyword = 'C' THEN 'KeyC' 
            WHEN Keyword = 'D' THEN 'KeyD' 
       END
```